# XMLWriter that ouput both string value and a file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I successfully created a way how to write an XML file using this:

```
Dim xw As XmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(path, xws)
```

and successfully create an XML into a string using this:

```
Dim sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
return sb.ToString();
```

Now what I want to achieve is to both have the string value and the xml output file. Is there a way to achieve this without using both method?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, what you want to do is output the string representation of your XML to a file. Replace `return sb.ToString()` with:

```
Using outfile As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\MyXmlFile.txt")
    outfile.Write(sb.ToString())
End Using
```

[StreamWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)